# List of dynamic data lists loaded asynchronously from server to be tested with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, karma-jasmine

I have a layout composed by a list of lists.

On each row an user click, its child list is retrieved from the server and rendered with some information, among others, money quantities.

How can I iterate over all list items `<ul> -> <li>` and per each element blocks or stay waiting until the data is retrieved and rendered so that I can test the quantity rendered is correct?

All this using `protractor`, of course.

Was trying to use something like this before:

```
var listItemsSelection       = element.all(by.css('.listItem')),
    listItemsExpandSelection = element.all(by.css('.icons-Expand'));

describe('Data screen - Rows', function () {
  //Given
  beforeEach(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < listItemsExpandSelection.count(); i++) {
      listItemsExpandSelection.get(i).click();

      browser.wait(function() {
        return browser.isElementPresent(elm);
      }, 500);
    }
  });

  it('Element exist and is informed properly', function () {
    listItemsExpandSelection.each(function (el) {
      var elm = el.element(by.css(".amountCell"));

      expect(el.element(by.css('amountCell'))).toBe('5,50 €');
    });

  });
});
```

By executing:

```
listItemsExpandSelection.each(function (element, index) { element.click(); });
```

Which is another way to iterate over a selection, I get an error like: *"UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (941, 524). Other"*. Since, on each clicked row, new data is retrieved and show, so the next sibling is pushed down a bit and therefore, not clickable.

An HTML snippet would be the following:

When first row still not clicked:

```
<ul>
  <li class="listItem"><i class="icons-Expand"></i></li>
  <!-- n elements -->
</ul>
```

And after clicked and waited for a few milliseconds:

```
<ul>
  <li class="listItem">
    <i class="icons-Expand"></i>
    <ul>
      <li class="listSubItem"></li>
      <!-- n sub-elements -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- n elements -->
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the HTML representation of your nested lists.

Comment: Updated and added the HTML representation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should click the `li` element and wait for the sublist to appear:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

listItemsSelection.each(function (el) {
    el.click();

    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el.element(by.css("li.listSubItem"))), 10000);

    // make expectations
});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work as expected.

Why? Simply because on each new sublist added, the DOM hierarchy is growing and the rest of "click()" events won't fire as expected due to:
"UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (896, 655). Other element would receive the click:"

Comment: @DavidPelayo is it an internal or public app? In other words, is there any chance I can reproduce the problem? Thanks.

Comment: To me, the ideal scenario should be in a way something like:

On each iteration of the each statement, JS should wait somehow until click() action completes, then the browser waits the presence of the sub-element, expectations run and then continues iterating, but I can't imagine how a piece of code like this would be.

And, yep, it's not public, therefore can't be accessed.

Comment: Try reversing an array. In this case list grow downward and you always stay at the top.Another option is to scroll using Javascript (you can get locator of an element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084537/webdriver-getlocation-in-protractor)

Comment: I will try that out and will back with the feedback. Thanks!